# python stubbing framework for properties

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, mockito, stub

Does anyone know a mocking- or stubbing-framework which allows stubbing **properties** or even **classproperties** like this decorator does?

```
class classproperty:
    """
    Decorator to  read-only static properties
    """
    def __init__(self, getter):
        self.getter = getter
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.getter(owner)

class Foo:
    _name = "Name"
    @classproperty
    def foo(cls):
        return cls._name
```

I'm currently using [mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito-python/wiki/Stubbing), but this doesn't allow stubbing of properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`unittest.mock.PropertyMock`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.PropertyMock) (available since Python 3.3):

```
from unittest import mock
with mock.patch.object(Foo, 'foo', new_callable=mock.PropertyMock) as m:
    m.return_value = 'nAME'
    assert Foo.foo == 'nAME'
```

**NOTE**: If you use Python version lower than 3.3, use [`mock`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock).